# Android: Media Player release and null issue?

Tags: android

I have a sound bite that plays on a click of a button (of 2 secs). On completion i have called a new activity and released the Media Player.

But my app crashes at this.

My code

```
final ImageButton TtriangleButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.triangleTriangle);
    TtriangleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            /* Code for playing the "Very Good" sound */    
            final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(shapeTriangleActivity.this, R.raw.applause);
            mediaPlayer.start();

            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    Intent myintent1 = new Intent(shapeTriangleActivity.this,LearningTimeMenu.class);
                    myintent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(myintent1);
                    mediaPlayer.release();

                }});
        }});
```

One MORE issue that i have is, at the release i have tried to add a NULL as well mediaPlayer = null; -- but i get a compilation error like "The final local variable mediaPlayer cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type".

Am stuck on this. Need help.

Updated with Error Log

10-31 14:54:45.800: E/AndroidRuntime(859): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040006

Also my files are .wav files. I have noticed that .mp3 files do not have this issue, even though they both are the same file size.

Comment: why do you try to null your variable ?

Answer (score 3):

Release media player before starting a new activity like this ::

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                Intent myintent1 = new Intent(shapeTriangleActivity.this,LearningTimeMenu.class);
                myintent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(myintent1);


            }});
```

Comment: Try to set media player as null after release it and also make one change that create media player instance globally .Hope it may help you :)

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way......

**-** You should `release` it, and then assign `null` **after completion** of the playing.

**-** Then again `initialize` the **media player** when you want to play another sound.

```
 mPlayer.start();
 mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

 @Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

             mPlayer.release();  // 
             mPlayer = null;

        }
});
```

**-** If you are playing only a 2sec sound clip, please use `SoundPool` to do this, as `SoundPool` is **apt for these kinda sounds-clips....**

**Here are few limitations of** `SoundPool`**:**

**-** Sound file should **Not exceed** 1 MB.

**-** Best result are obtained with `.wav` sound files, its even ok with `.mp3, .mp4, .m4a`

**-** Please go with `bitrate` of 128kb/sec and 22050KHz `sampling rate`, for complete playing of the sound-clip

Comment: In the above code - when i insert mPlayer = null; --> it gives me a compilation error of -> "The final local variable mediaPlayer cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type". Any idea why this is?

Comment: @Jasma Declare the `mPlayer` which is of type `MediaPlayer` at **Class scope.**

Comment: I can confirm that not setting MediaPlayer object = null to force immediate garbage collection can result in IllegalStateErrors later. In my case, I released the player in my activity's onDestroy() method but when I re-started the app I would get the error. Setting it to null after release() fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

First  `stop`
 the media player and then `release` it.